# JQuery clicking to show image, then making it disappear after delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a simple game of Simon, and I want the easiest way to code where if one of the four buttons is clicked, it changes the image for a second or so (on mode), plays a sound, then goes back to its original color. Right now I've searched, but everything I've seen has to do with divs, or other types of questions.

As of now the button changes to the on button image, plays the sound, but when I try any function to hide or fadeOut or anything of that sort, it goes to a strange greyish color, but does not disappear. I've tried to use attr() to set the image back to what it originally was with a delay in between, but that doesn't work, either. The code is long, but I'll post what's relevant...

```
    <audio src="sounds/1.mp3" id ="snd1"></audio>
    <audio src="sounds/2.mp3" id ="snd2"></audio>
    <audio src="sounds/3.mp3" id ="snd3"></audio>
    <audio src="sounds/4.mp3" id ="snd4"></audio>
    <div id="juego">
        <div id="simon">
            <div id="c1"><img id ="c1i" src="imgs/d1.png"></div>
            <div id="c2"><img id ="c2i" src="imgs/d2.png"></div>
            <div id="c3"><img id ="c3i" src="imgs/d3.png"></div>
            <div id="c4"><img id ="c4i" src="imgs/d4.png"></div>
        </div>
```

and from my js file...

```
    $("#c1").on("click", function() {
            $("#c1i").attr("src", "imgs/1.png").hide("slow");
            $("#snd1")[0].play();
});
```

edit: I will also add that clicking the button as of now only lets me click it once to perform the function. After one click, it just greys out. No color change, no sound played. Mystifying to me...

Comment: Image `fadeOut` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zUhfC/. Is it really becoming grey or you've property `background-color:grey;` in your css?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("#c1").on("click", function() {
       // change the image , and make sure this image path exists ...
      $("#c1i").attr("src", "imgs/1.png");
      // make it disappear and play the sound after 1 second
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#c1i").hide();
        $("#snd1")[0].play();
      },1000);

});
```

Comment: Hmm that makes it disappear after a second (and play the sound after a second, which I will have to move up before the setTimeout function. But after it hides, the original image does not return on #c1i and I can no longer click on the button to perform the function again.

Comment: I think I got it!!

    $("#c1").on("click", function() {
       // change the image , and make sure this image path exists ...
      $("#c1i").attr("src", "imgs/1.png");
              $("#snd1")[0].play();
      // make it disappear and play the sound after 1 second
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#c1i").attr("src", "imgs/d1.png");
      },1000);

});

With your help! :)

Comment: you want to hide it or exchange it with another one ?

if you wanna exchange the img change the ` $("#c1i").hide();` 
with ` $("#c1i").attr("src","NEW_URL");`



if it's helps don't forget to mark the question as answered

Comment: left to my answer there is a little mark , just below the voting arrows